# What is the logic behind the present arrangement of Seven Sacraments?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments

As per Catholic Catechism, the Seven Sacraments are sequenced in the following order :

Baptism, Confirmation , Eucharist, Penance, Anointing of the Sick, Holy Orders, and Matrimony

But, that is not the sequence in which one receives the Sacraments as one grows up. My question is: What is the logic behind the present random arrangement of the Seven Sacraments in Catholic Catechism ?

Comment: Why do you think the order they are listed in is important?

Comment: That is actually the traditional chronological order for the first five sacraments.  Confirmation and Eucharist got reversed in the West due to a problem relating to the infrequent presence of the bishop (who is the ordinary minister of Confirmation).  Since the West wanted to maintain the bishop as the minister of Confirmation the sacrament often ended up being delayed, thus resulting in a new tradition.  Certain bishops like Samuel Aquila are restoring the original order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Catholic Catechism is a teaching tool about the Catholic faith. The Teaching Magisterium of the Church could have chosen another sequence for the seven sacraments, but it stayed with the most common and traditional way of listing the sacramennts.

Why this sequencing of the sacraments?

The first three sacraments mentioned are those involved in Christian initiation.

> According to the Catechism of the Catholic Church, “the sacraments of Christian initiation — baptism, confirmation and the Eucharist — lay the foundations of every Christian life. ... The faithful are born anew by baptism, strengthened by the Sacrament of Confirmation, and receive in the Eucharist the food of eternal life” (No. 1212). The Catechism goes on to say that, “The holy Eucharist completes our Christian initiation” (No. 1322). - [Restored order for sacraments a growing trend](http://Restored%20order%20for%20sacraments%20a%20growing%20trend)

Baptism, penance and the anointing of the sick are sometimes referred to as the
sacraments of the dead and as such are at the faithful's disposition when in need. Since we should be in the state of grace before getting married or upon being ordained as a priest these sacraments are placed next in the list.

> Those sacraments which can be validly and fruitfully received when a person is not in the state of grace. They are baptism, penance, and, if needed, anointing of the sick. These sacraments confer or restore sanctifying grace and confer actual graces when received by one who is already in God's friendship. - [Sacraments of the Dead](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36198)

Most of the faithful will eventually choose marriage over Holy Orders and thus marriage is normally listed as the sixth sacrament and Holy Orders as the seventh.

Many Catholics do have a different sequence for the seven sacraments of the Church, such as the following:

> [The Seven Sacraments of the Catholic Church](http://stanthonyes.com/sacraments/)
>
> I. Baptism
>
> II. Reconciliation (Confession)
>
> III. Eucharist (Communion)
>
> IV. Confirmation
>
> V. Marriage
>
> VI. Holy Orders
>
> VII. Anointing of the Sick (Extreme Unction)